# Server exit called, exiting the JVM now

Tags: jboss

I am using JBoss AS 6.1.0

and facing the problem of JBoss Crashing. It works fine on HTTP. But after configuring SSL crashing issue started occurring on HTTPS. It is currently in Production crashing twice a day. Please help......any idea or clue regarding this irritating issue.

Mirza Abdul Rehman
NetSol WFS-DAS

```
2014-06-16 22:30:00,899 INFO  [org.jboss.system.server.jmx.JMXKernel] (Thread-59) Server exit called, exiting the JVM now!
2014-06-16 22:30:00,899 INFO  [STDOUT] (Thread-1) Posting Shutdown Request to the server...
2014-06-16 22:30:00,899 INFO  [org.jboss.bootstrap.impl.base.server.AbstractServer] (Thread-60) Stopping: JBossAS [6.1.0.Final "Neo"]
2014-06-16 22:30:00,899 INFO  [org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol] (Thread-60) Pausing Coyote HTTP/1.1 on http-0.0.0.0-8080
2014-06-16 22:30:00,899 INFO  [org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol] (Thread-60) Stopping Coyote HTTP/1.1 on http-0.0.0.0-8080
2014-06-16 22:30:00,930 INFO  [org.apache.coyote.ajp.AjpProtocol] (Thread-60) Pausing Coyote AJP/1.3 on ajp-0.0.0.0-8009
2014-06-16 22:30:00,930 INFO  [org.apache.coyote.ajp.AjpProtocol] (Thread-60) Stopping Coyote AJP/1.3 on ajp-0.0.0.0-8009
2014-06-16 22:30:00,946 INFO  [org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol] (Thread-60) Pausing Coyote HTTP/1.1 on http-8443
2014-06-16 22:30:00,946 INFO  [org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol] (Thread-60) Stopping Coyote HTTP/1.1 on http-8443
```

Comment: The log snippet seems to state that it was told to shut down, it didn't crash. What is logged just before the current snippet? Prehaps anything at WARN or ERROR level?

Comment: have you solved your problem?

Comment: This issue just gone after the re-installation of operating system.